# Error in Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: data, fourier-analysis

Consider [this data](https://justpaste.it/59qtt). I would like to plot it via it Fourier discrete sine transform. However, I am getting a slight offset, as seen here

```
pdat = ListPlot[data];
ur = FourierDST[data];
n = Length[ur];
pdatFour = Plot[Sqrt[2/(n + 1)] Sum[ur[[r]] Sin[Pi/(n + 1) r s], {r, 1, n}], {s, 0, n}];

Show[pdat, pdatFour]
```

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: The reason is math, not Mathematica.: see [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) for explanation.

Comment: I think some multiplier is omitted, when editing.  It is not a good practice to  edit the question, but not to indicate changes.  It is not a good pratice not to present your `data`.

Comment: @user64494 The data is presented. The edits are trivial, and they do not change the question. In case you are wondering, you can track the editing by clicking "edited (...)". Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are scaling the output of the DST incorrectly. You can fix the offset by using Plot[Sqrt[4/(n + 1)] Sum[ur[[r]] Sin[Pi/(n + 1) r s], {r, 1, n}], {s, 0, n}, PlotRange -> All]; ( i.e., replace Sqrt[2/(n+1)] with Sqrt[4/(n+1)] ). A more elegant solution is to pay attention to the four kinds of DST shown in the Details section of the help file. You seem to be using type 1. Hence use:

```
ur = FourierDST[data,1];
```

and your plots align.